# What are some Tornado Cash alternatives?

Tags: private-blockchain, privacy, anonymity, tornado-cash

I used Tornado Cash in its earlier days, but I stopped using it after it faced sanctions. What are some other dApps available that can be used for private transactions on Ethereum? I'm not referring to mixers and tumblers; I'm interested in on-chain trustless solutions, not centralized mixers like converting ETH to Bitcoin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking for a decentralized solution rather than a centralized one, since most tumblers and mixers are controlled by entities in the backend, I personally use [beacon.cash](https://Beacon.Cash). It uses Genesis as a means to anonymize transactions by routing funds through the Genesis router, ensuring the deposit remains untraceable. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Looking for a Tornado Cash alternative? Enter LNDRY, my top pick for both mixing and bridging crypto.

LNDRY is all about speed – lightning-fast transactions without breaking the bank on fees.

Privacy is a highlight; it's like a guardian mixing up your transactions, ensuring no one traces back to your wallet.

Hold up, it's not just about privacy – as a holder, you get reflections, meaning passive income while keeping things secure.

Explore all the details on their official website here and dive into specifics here if curiosity strikes.

Dapp: https://dapp.lndry.xyz/
Docs: https://docs.lndry.xyz/